# What is the equivalent of Vaadin 8 Link component in Vaadin 17 Flow?

Tags: hyperlink, vaadin

In Vaadin 8 I had the following code to jump to an external page:

```
final Link link = new Link("Google", new ExternalResource("http://www.google.com"));
layout.addComponent(link);
```

In Vaadin 17 Flow I cannot find a reference to "Link".

What should I do?

Comment: For future reference, there is a comparison matrix showing the v14+ equivalent of v8 components: https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/upgrading/v8/5-components/#components.

Comment: Also note that Vaadin 17 is no longer supported, so it's not necessarily an ideal version to upgrade to (unless you plan to continue upgrading even further, of course). The latest stable version is 22, and there are already pre-releases of 23 available as well.

Answer (score 5):

The replacement for `Link` is `Anchor` in Vaadin Flow.  See https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-anchor

Also it is now way easier to just use plain "HTML tags" with Flow -- if
you prefer that.